# Which process - in windows - changes system settings

Tags: windows, windows-registry, process, process-monitor

I'm currently writing a program that changes certain system settings. For most of those settings, I was able to find information on registry keys on the internet. For others, however, I wasn't able to find anything on the internet. So I tried to find out myself by using Microsoft/Sysinternals Process Monitor. I've been filtering for write access to Registry and for process explorer.exe. Then I've changed a setting. No luck with that. Then I tried the process DllHost.exe. Also no luck. So my question to you is, which process do I have to look for to find out the Registry Keys behind system settings?

Answer (score 0):

The tool you're using to change the setting is probably just calling a windows API to make the change.  So, which tool are you using to change the setting - that's the one to watch.

Would it not be easier to,

1. export the registry
2. change the setting
3. export the registry
4. compare the two exports to find out what changed

Comment: I'm changing the system settings directly out of windows. And I'm already watching the WinAPI using Process Monitor. However, I don't know which process to watch, since there are lots of them. While your idea of comparing the two exports sounds nice in theory, there are just too many changes to registry for this to work.